# how does DataFrameGroupBy.apply handle large dataframes with duplicate index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

Suppose that we have a large dataframe with duplicate index,

```py
# IPython
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: from numpy.random import randint
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': randint(1, 10, 10000)}, index=randint(1, 10, 10000))
```

and we want to group by column `'a'` and do some operations using `apply`, such as (just do nothing in `apply`)

```py
In [4]: df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x)
```

which will take a long time:

```py
In [5]: %timeit df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x)
19.9 s ± 322 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If the size goes bigger, it becames unbearable. However, if we `reset_index` first, it goes fast.

```py
In [6]: %timeit df.reset_index(drop=True).groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x)
2.24 ms ± 60.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Then my question is how `apply` handle duplicate index, and why it's so slow.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: according the document.`GroupBy.apply` is flexible but slow.so what you intend to do.maybe we can solve it by another way.

Comment: @nay, yes. But it becomes especially slow in the case I proposed above. So I think there may be something special when it handles df with duplicate index.